# How to change VS Code terminal selection UI from tabs back to dropdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code

While I was working, I mistakenly clicked on an option and that changed the UI of the terminal on VS Code entirely + it is extremely annoying.

Here's what it looks like now:
[image]

And this is what it is supposed to look like:
[image]

As you can see, it has stripped off multiple options as well. I am using WSL on Windows if that helps for the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it.

Go to your settings.json file and update this:

```
"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": false,
```

Setting the above property to false should fix your terminal from that annoying UI/UX.

It fixed my UI back to this:

[image]