# Terminal Commands disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code terminal buttons disappeared for some reason. Here's where they are now:

[image: The current situation]

I want it to be like this:

[image: The desired situation]

Does someone know how to change it back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode: Terminal Style Changed Mistakenly while working, how do I undo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554244/vscode-terminal-style-changed-mistakenly-while-working-how-do-i-undo)

Comment: I did what the person there said to do but it was already like that in the settings.json file

Comment: Are you sure you put the correct setting and in the correct settings.json? (There is user/global, workspace, and folder settings). [It works normally on my env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdFyR.gif). If it really doesn't on yours, please [edit] to provide more info: VS Code version, OS, and what exactly you put in settings.json.